# Mypy type hints for arguments which are pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, type-hinting, mypy, typing

I have the following, which I would expect to raise an error:

```py
# check.py
import pandas as pd

def f(s : str) -> None:
    print(s)

def main() -> None:
    f(s = pd.Series([1,2]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However, `mypy check.py` returns `Success: no issues found in 1 source file`.

How is one supposed to provide typehints for pandas series?

In the pandas code (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/98e22297bb66f81ff4c1d4f1c3277cfe8c6b9ce7/pandas/core/series.py#L511) there's:

```py
    def _constructor(self) -> type[Series]:
        return Series
```

`type[Series]`, I'm not sure if this is how we're supposed to typehint series though?

## edit

updating the code to:

```py
# check.py
import pandas as pd

def f(s : str) -> None:
    print(s)

def g(s : str) -> None:
    print(s)

def main() -> None:
    f(s = pd.Series([1,2]))
    g(s = 12.9)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

gives the output:

```
check.py:12: error: Argument "s" to "g" has incompatible type "float"; expected "str"  [arg-type]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a [common issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1519) in mypy - it will not check types on functions if they don't have the output type annotation - you need to add `-> None` to `main`.

This will then give you the error:

```
test.py:7: error: Argument "s" to "f" has incompatible type "Series[int]"; expected "str"
```

Which can be fixed with the annotation `s: pd.Series[int]`

---

So this is the full script:

```py
import pandas as pd

def f(s: pd.Series[int]) -> None:
    print(s)

def main() -> None:
    f(s = pd.Series([1,2]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

*Note: You may also need to* `pip install data-science-types` *as depending on how you installed pandas it may not come with type stubs.*

Comment: thanks - did you try the original code? I just replace with `-> None` and there was still no error output, which there presumably should. I guess there must be some odd config or something in this repo :/

Comment: yeah, copied your code exactly, got no mypy errors, then added the `-> None` and got the error I copied into the answer.

Comment: It did at first say that it was skipping all checks on the pandas-related code due to not knowing the types - have you tried installing the data-science-types library to add those?